# flutter dart get.http response giving html instead of json api

Tags: html, json, api, flutter, dart

Yesterday the code works and returned me api json but not anymore now.

This is the url im using:
https://www.instagram.com/p/CKNvnNOFPol/?__a=1

And this is what im getting from that link:
Image: https://prnt.sc/xszvri

this is the code

```
    void getContentPost() async {
var response =  await http.get('https://www.instagram.com/p/CKNvnNOFPol/?__a=1');
print(response.body);

Map data = jsonDecode(response.body);
print(data);}
```

and i used elevated button to call getContentPost();

results:

```
Syncing files to device sdk gphone x86 arm...
Reloaded 1 of 623 libraries in 1,120ms.
I/flutter ( 2137): <!DOCTYPE html>
I/flutter ( 2137): <html lang="en" class="no-js not-logged-in client-root">
I/flutter ( 2137):     <head>
I/flutter ( 2137):         <meta charset="utf-8">
I/flutter ( 2137):         <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
I/flutter ( 2137): 
I/flutter ( 2137):         <title>
I/flutter ( 2137): Login • Instagram
I/flutter ( 2137): </title>
I/flutter ( 2137): 
I/flutter ( 2137):         
I/flutter ( 2137):         <meta name="robots" content="noimageindex, noarchive">
I/flutter ( 2137):         <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="default">
I/flutter ( 2137):         <meta name="mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
I/flutter ( 2137):         <meta name="theme-color" content="#ffffff">
I/flutter ( 2137):         <meta id="viewport" name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, viewport-fit=cover">
I/flutter ( 2137):         <link rel="manifest" href="/data/manifest.json">
I/flutter ( 2137): 
I/flutter ( 2137):         <link rel="preload" href="/static/bundles/metro/ConsumerUICommons.css/963b2667869f.css" as="style" type="text/css" crossorigin="anonymous" />
I/flutter ( 2137): <link rel="preload" href="/static/bundles/metro/ConsumerAsyncCommons.css/0608bd6190e0.css" as="style" type="text/css" crossorigin="anonymous" />
I/flutter ( 2137): <link rel="preload" href="/static/bundle
E/flutter ( 2137): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(186)] Unhandled Exception: FormatException: Unexpected character (at character 1)
E/flutter ( 2137): <!DOCTYPE html>
E/flutter ( 2137): ^
E/flutter ( 2137): 
E/flutter ( 2137): #0      _ChunkedJsonParser.fail (dart:convert-patch/convert_patch.dart:1404:5)
E/flutter ( 2137): #1      _ChunkedJsonParser.parseNumber (dart:convert-patch/convert_patch.dart:1271:9)
E/flutter ( 2137): #2      _ChunkedJsonParser.parse (dart:convert-patch/convert_patch.dart:936:22)
E/flutter ( 2137): #3      _parseJson (dart:convert-patch/convert_patch.dart:40:10)
E/flutter ( 2137): #4      JsonDecoder.convert (dart:convert/json.dart:506:36)
E/flutter ( 2137): #5      JsonCodec.decode (dart:convert/json.dart:157:41)
E/flutter ( 2137): #6      jsonDecode (dart:convert/json.dart:96:10)
E/flutter ( 2137): #7      _HomeState.getContentPost (package:instagram_content_downloader_new/main.dart:41:16)
E/flutter ( 2137): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter ( 2137):
```

Comment: I think the api you are requesting is a HTML page, So how would it return the json response ?

Comment: Did you use [this package](https://pub.dev/packages/http)?

Comment: @SamChan Yes i im using http package

Comment: @Mukul i dont get what you mean :( isnt that the api link i mentioned above? there's graphql etc etc. im new so i dont really know. and how can i get the json information from it

Comment: The html means that your API exists some error. However, I try to run your code in my device, but I can get the data correctly.

Comment: if you guys see the results ive mentioned above you can see "<html lang="en" class="no-js not-logged-in client-root">" 

it says not logged in, so i login using instagram api simple dispay with success getting access_token in return but still after trying to execute the code above that i mentioned I am getting the same results = which is "not logged in" . :/ been googling eversince yet have not found any solution to it :(((((

Comment: @MinzMaliq Did you find any solution for that?

Answer (score 0):

I tried your code locally and it works without issues. Here's the snippet of the code I've tried.

```dart
Future<void> _request() async {
  var response = await http.get(Uri.parse('https://www.instagram.com/p/CKNvnNOFPol/?__a=1'));
  debugPrint('Response: ${response.body}');
}
```

The http request will only return an html response if `?__a=1` was removed from the endpoint url. Make sure that the endpoint that you're using is correct.